# What "regexp-literal" means in ruby's "=~" method?

Tags: ruby, regex

In [Ruby regex doc](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Regexp.html), method `rxp =~ str` require `regexp literal` when somebody want to assign named captures to local variables.
So what is `regexp literal` in ruby?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`Regexp`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Regexp.html) already mention this :

> A Regexp holds a regular expression, used to match a pattern against strings. **Regexps are created using the /.../ and %r{...} literals**, and by the Regexp::new constructor.

Comment: `The assignment does not occur if the regexp is not a literal.  
re = /(?<lhs>\w+)\s*=\s*(?<rhs>\w+)/
re =~ "  x = y  "
p lhs    # undefined local variable
p rhs    # undefined local variable`
So why this fail to assign to lhs&rhs variables?

Comment: Because on the left hand side of the `=~` operator you have a variable (`re`) not a literal.  This would work: `/(?<lhs>\w+)\s*=\s*(?<rhs>\w+)/ =~ " x = y ";p lhs;p rhs`